# Python data sent to web

Tags: python-3.x

Web form filling from python3 script. But not actual filling data in website. Please tell me how to fix it.

```
import requests

parameters = {'Name': 'Dave', 'Message' : 'Hello World'}

cookies = {'security' : 'low', 'PHPSESSID':'uiuktsbfa1ckahrmkmv6p7drm6'}

r = requests.post("http://myweb.local", data = parameters , cookies=cookies)

print(r.text)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sMIm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
import requests

parameters = {'Name': 'Dave', 'Message' : 'Hello World'}

cookies = {'security' : 'low', 'PHPSESSID':'uiuktsbfa1ckahrmkmv6p7drm6'}

r = requests.post("http://myweb.local/demopage.php", data = parameters , cookies=cookies)

print(r.text)
```

you change url this -->http://myweb.local/demopage.php